# How to add a button to Xcode Editor

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, xcodekit

[image]
See this left side button to "Show the standard Editor" button is a custom button from https://sympli.io/downloads/xcode

I know that Alcatraz era ended, but this Sympli plugin, I'm using in latest stable Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)

[image]

How can I add my own button like this in Xcode? I have searched in XcodeKit but not found an answer.

Thanks