# Where to find Framework headers with Swift syntax in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

If go to AppDelegate, press command, and click on `UIResponder`, it takes me to this screen:

[image: screenshot]

But I want to find this documentation in Finder. I already tried the right click - show in Finder option; it is not working.

I found an Objective-C version of all the header for all frameworks, I am very much interested in where the Swift version docs (or headers) are stored. I have searched almost everywhere in Xcode source. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: What about typing `import UIKit` at the top of a Swift file and command clicking that?

Comment: @shim I was investigating private frameworks and Xcode source in order to do : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691088/how-to-add-a-button-to-xcode-editor  and it'll really great if I find all source in swift, because I'm not much familiar with objc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift version of the Cocoa framework headers is not “stored” anywhere. It is generated in real time by translating the header from Objective-C to Swift. That is why it is called a generated header, while the Objective-C is called the original.

Comment: thanks for the answer, if you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691088/how-to-add-a-button-to-xcode-editor it will be really helpful, Thank you :)